Why is auto-fill-mode in sh-mode not always putting a space after the leading '#' comment character?
I'm trying to find why the auto-fill-mode of a sh-mode buffer (with "# " as comment) sometimes does and sometimes does not put a space character after the leading '#' comment. As a secondary concern is the behaviour controlling the comment indentation.
Environment: Emacs 29.3
The context is best explained with some examples:
Example 1: Space is inserted after '#' as expected (but indentation does not seem to work):
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                                                         
# Inside this first example, without the header text placed at the beginning of                                                                                                                                     
# the file to see if the comment indentation works properly and IT DOES. all                                                                                                                                      
# is OK here!                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#    Testing the indentation now.  The expectation would be that the next line                                                                                                                                    
# is indented but it is NOT.                                                                                                                                                                                      

Example 2: There's a missing space after the comment character:
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                                                         
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
# This is an example of the comment text wrapping inside a sh-mode buffer when                                                                                                                                    
#the auto-fill-mode is active and the above text is inside the file. Note that                                                                                                                                    
#there is no space at the beginning of the line!  There should be one! And it                                                                                                                                     
#seems that the driving factor is the presence of TWO lines with empty                                                                                                                                            
#comments!  If I delete one of them, then the behaviour gets back to what I                                                                                                                                       
#expect.      

The behaviour of auto-fill-mode seems to be affected by the text above and the presence of comment lines that have only whitespace.  Is this expected??
To look into this I wrote a command that prints the buffer values of several variables related to commenting and filling.  This is what this shows for example2 (and its the same for example1).
----Comment controlling variables from example2 --- Thursday, June 13, 2024 @ 10:19:29 -----                                                                                                                      
----- List of comment variables:

- major-mode                              : sh-mode
- fill-column                             : 78
- normal-auto-fill-function               : #[128 "\304\300\301^C#\207" [smie-auto-fill #[128 "\301\302\300!^B\"\207" [normal-auto-fill-function apply default-value] 4 "

(fn &rest ARGS)"] :around nil apply] 5 advice]
- auto-fill-function                      : #[128 "\304\300\301^C#\207" [smie-auto-fill #[128 "\301\302\300!^B\"\207" [normal-auto-fill-function apply default-value] 4 "

(fn &rest ARGS)"] :around nil apply] 5 advice]
- comment-add                             : 0
- comment-auto-fill-only-comments         : nil
- comment-column                          : 32
- comment-combine-change-calls            : t
- comment-continue                        : nil
- comment-empty-lines                     : t
- comment-end                             : ""
- comment-end-can-be-escaped              : nil
- comment-end-skip                        : "[  ]*\\(\\s>\\|
\\)"
- comment-fill-column                     : nil
- comment-indent-function                 : comment-indent-default
- comment-inline-offset                   : 1
- comment-insert-comment-function         : nil
- comment-line-break-function             : comment-indent-new-line
- comment-multi-line                      : nil
- comment-padding                         : " "
- comment-quote-nested                    : t
- comment-quote-nested-function           : comment-quote-nested-default
- comment-region-function                 : comment-region-default
- comment-start                           : "# "
- comment-start-skip                      : "#+[         ]*"
- comment-style                           : indent
- comment-styles                          : ((plain nil nil nil nil "Start in column 0 (do not indent), as in Emacs-20") (indent-or-triple nil nil nil multi-char "Start in column 0, but only for single-char st\
arters") (indent nil nil nil t "Full comment per line, ends not aligned") (aligned nil t nil t "Full comment per line, ends aligned") (box nil t t t "Full comment per line, ends aligned, + top and bottom") (ex\
tra-line t nil t t "One comment for all lines, end on a line by itself") (multi-line t nil nil t "One comment for all lines, end on last commented line") (box-multi t t t t "One comment for all lines, + top an\
d bottom"))
- comment-use-global-state                : t
- comment-use-syntax                      : t
- comment-use-syntax-ppss                 : t


I tried changing the normal-auto-fill-function and auto-fill-function to do-auto-fill but that did not affect the described behaviour.
UPDATE: I tested with emacs -Q and the behaviour seems to change, but not always; the error remains in some cases while the behaviour is correct in others.  More testing is required to pin-point.

If you've determined that something in your init file causes the behavior, then bisect it to find out what causes it. See Debugging Techniques. Just eyeballing the different minor modes is unreliable: there is probably something causing the problem that you wouldn't have guessed in a million years (give or take :-) ...)

Granted, my next step will be to single step using the debugger.  It would help if anyone knows if there are know variables or functions that control this, after the comment, indentation. Aside from the ones I listed.

Don't use the debugger: bisecting your init file as described in the reference is much faster..

Strange, I started bisecting and checking with emacs -Q in parallel.  And I got the error with emacs -Q.  I wonder if this has anything to do with the contents of the file.  So it seems the error is also occurring with a virgin Emacs, at least in some cases.   I should probably update my update.

If you can reproduce it with -Q, then post a step-by-step recipe of how to reproduce it.
